# I can't run my .bat file,but i can run my .xml file.How i will run that .bat file?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

-This is a simple java project.
   -I used Testng in it.
   -When I run my .xml file by Testng then, I can see my script has run on the remote machines.
   -but when I create the .bat file, then that has not executed.
   -I am using selenium grid with Jenkins.So, please share a code on it.
Showing error message on my cmd window like these:-

```
set classpath=D:\selenium\selenium_grid\bin;D:\selenium\selenium_grid\lib\*
new chrome options<> is preferred to DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
```

Code :

```
package grid_hub_node;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Demo {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Parameters({ "system" })
    @Test
    public void testdemo(String system) throws InterruptedException
    {
            if (system.equalsIgnoreCase("pc1")) {
                try {
                    String nodeurl;
                nodeurl="http://192.168.1.115:5090/wd/hub";
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
                capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
                driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeurl),capabilities);
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.get("https://www.ebay.in/");
                String title_name=driver.getTitle();
                System.out.println(title_name);
                Thread.sleep(7000l);
                driver.quit();
                }
            catch(MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}  
              else if (system.equalsIgnoreCase("pc2")) {
                try {
                    String nodeurl;
                    nodeurl="http://192.168.1.112:6760/wd/hub";
                    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                    capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
                    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
                    driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeurl),capabilities);
                    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    driver.get("http://sdrc.co.in/");
                    String title_name=driver.getTitle();
                    System.out.println(title_name);
                    Thread.sleep(7000l);
                    driver.quit();
                    }
                catch(MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}
                else if (system.equalsIgnoreCase("pc3")) {
                    try {
                        String nodeurl;
                        nodeurl="http://192.168.1.102:4051/wd/hub";
                        DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
                        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
                        driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeurl),capabilities);
                        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                        driver.manage().window().maximize();
                        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/");
                        String title_name=driver.getTitle();
                        System.out.println(title_name);
                        Thread.sleep(7000l);
                        driver.quit();
                        }
                    catch(MalformedURLException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }}
                    else if (system.equalsIgnoreCase("pc4")) {
                        try {
                            String nodeurl;
                            nodeurl="http://192.168.1.121:7611/wd/hub";
                            DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                            capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
                            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
                            driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeurl),capabilities);
                            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                            driver.manage().window().maximize();
                            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            driver.get("https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows");
                            String title_name=driver.getTitle();
                            System.out.println(title_name);
                            Thread.sleep(7000l);
                            driver.quit();
                            }
                        catch(MalformedURLException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }}
                    else if (system.equalsIgnoreCase("pc5")) {
                        try {
                            String nodeurl;
                            nodeurl="http://192.168.1.177:6474/wd/hub";
                            DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                            capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
                            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
                            driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeurl),capabilities);
                            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                            driver.manage().window().maximize();
                            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            driver.get("https://cricket.yahoo.com/");
                            String title_name=driver.getTitle();
                            System.out.println(title_name);
                            Thread.sleep(7000l);
                            driver.quit();
                            }
                        catch(MalformedURLException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }}
                        else if (system.equalsIgnoreCase("pc6")) {
                            try {
                                String nodeurl;
                                nodeurl="http://192.168.1.141:5871/wd/hub";
                                DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                                capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
                                capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
                                driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeurl),capabilities);
                                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                                driver.get("http://www.fifa.com/");
                                String title_name=driver.getTitle();
                                System.out.println(title_name);
                                Thread.sleep(7000l);
                                driver.quit();
                                }
                            catch(MalformedURLException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }}}}
```

TestNG.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" thread-count="10" parallel="tests">
  <test name="Test1">
  <parameter name="system" value="pc1"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="grid_hub_node.Grid_Demo_parallel"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 


   <test name="Test2">
  <parameter name="system" value="pc2"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="grid_hub_node.Grid_Demo_parallel"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 



   <test name="Test3">
  <parameter name="system" value="pc3"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="grid_hub_node.Grid_Demo_parallel"/>
    </classes>
  </test>


   <test name="Test4">
  <parameter name="system" value="pc4"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="grid_hub_node.Grid_Demo_parallel"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Test5">
  <parameter name="system" value="pc5"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="grid_hub_node.Grid_Demo_parallel"/>
    </classes>
  </test>


   <test name="Test6">
  <parameter name="system" value="pc6"/>
     <classes>
      <class name="grid_hub_node.Grid_Demo_parallel"/>
    </classes>
  </test>


</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

bat file :

```
set projectLocation=D:\selenium\selenium_grid
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml
pause
```

Comment: your error message not give useful information. is possible for you put your project in github, thus we can download and debug on local, pelase remove sense code before submit, you can only leave code to only open a public website, other can be remove, but keep the bin and lib folder also the xm and bat file

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: @yong Here is my git hub URL https://github.com/krishsagar/selenium_grid.git


I want to create a bat file for Jenkins, that bat file should run the testng.xml  file.

Comment: Try change the first line in your bat file to `set projectLocation=%~dp0` and make sure there is a folder: lib under `D:\selenium\selenium_grid`, then `selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar` and `testng-6.9.10.jar` under folder 'lib' . I guess you can copy them from you machine: `D:/Laxman/test/`

Comment: After above all set, open a cmd window on your local machine,  cd D:\selenium\selenium_grid , then run full.bat  to see the bat file work or not, before move to jenkins.

Comment: For the message 'new chrome options<> is preferred to ..', it's just used the old API in your code, but the old api still work, it's not the root cause.  The root cause is you configure the library in Eclipse from another folder not from `<project folder>\lib`. But you set  bat file classpath to  `<project folder>\lib`,  so the bat file can't find library when run by jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The error gives us some hint about the issues as follows :

```
set classpath=D:\selenium\selenium_grid\bin;D:\selenium\selenium_grid\lib\*
new chrome options<> is preferred to DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
```

The main issue seems to be in **Setting the `classpath`**

### Solution

Follow the steps :

- Get project location from your IDE (e.g. Eclipse), go to the location on your system, create a directory "lib"
- Dump all the libraries (Selenium jars, TestNG) in the "lib" directory.
- From the Project Directory, through CLIP provide the following classpath:

  ```
  C:\Users\<user_name>\<ProjectWorkspace>\<ProjectName>>set classpath=C:\Users\<user_name>\<ProjectWorkspace>\<ProjectName>\bin;C:\<user_name>\<ProjectWorkspace>\<ProjectName>\lib\*;
  ```
- Execute testng.xml from the CLI as follows:

  ```
  C:\<user_name>\<ProjectWorkspace>\<ProjectName>>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
  ```
- Observe the Testcase gets executed.
- Within the  create a new text document and add the following code:

  ```
  java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
  ```
- Save as "run.bat"
- Execute the script & verify Testcase gets executed.

Comment: For the message 'new chrome options<> is preferred to ..', it's just he used the old API in his code, but the old api still work.